# DIV - toggle up

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I need help with div' showing up.

I know, that code:

```
$( "#Button" ).click(function() {
  $('#leftDiv').toggle(2000);
});
```

will make my leftDiv dissappear (when I click Button), but what should I do to set my div default-hided(toggled down?) so that after I click Button, leftDiv should toggle up (appear)?

Comment: use http://api.jquery.com/show/ -- `toggle` - as the name implies - toggles between shown/hidden whereas `show` just shows the element(s) regardless of their actual visibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the div hidden when the page loads, then .hide() it first:

```
$('#leftDiv').hide();
$( "#Button" ).click(function() {
  $('#leftDiv').toggle(2000);
});
```

Comment: Yay so easy.... thanks :) another thing - how can I show different images depending on which button is clicked? There is no $('#leftDiv').image(); function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the div to be hidden on load, you would do something like:

```
function load() {
document.getElementById("leftDiv").style.visibility="hidden";
}

<body onload="load"></body>
```

Would that not work?

Answer (score 0):

```
var $leftDiv = $('#leftDiv');
var $button = $("#Button");

$leftDiv.hide();

$button.on('click', function() {
  $leftDiv.toggle(2000);
});
```